# Book/Online Video Lectures/Notes Recommendation for Analysis(topics mentioned)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am going to start a first course in Analysis soon in university this semester (in around a week).

Can anyone please recommend me good books/online notes or video lectures that can help me in studying analysis? I'll be studying the following topics:

> - Real Numbers:Field axioms, order axioms, bounded sets, completeness
>     axioms
>
>   - Sequences
>   - Series
>   - Limits of functions
>   - Differentiation
>   - Topology of R

So any books/notes/videos that target these areas? Also, please keep in mind that I'm not particularly amazing at math. I'm a slow learner and hence materials that are dumbed down will be preferred so I can better understand analysis.

Thanks.

Comment: Best book is the book from your course. If you have free time try The Way of Analysis by Strichartz

Answer (score 2):

This [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/27717/edit) give you free acsses to MIT courses 
and [this](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYO_jab_esuFRV4b17AJtAw) gives you access to videos tools along with the following with multiple references on calculus and real analysis for beginners
[Calculus book recommendations (for complete beginner)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner) and [Good First Course in real analysis book for self study](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188255/good-first-course-in-real-analysis-book-for-self-study)
 also see this [Online Course for Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593303/online-course-for-real-analysis) and [Video Lectures that closely follow Rudin's Real Analysis/Royden's Real Analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913851/video-lectures-that-closely-follow-rudins-real-analysis-roydens-real-analysis)

also [book recommendation for real analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207632/book-recommendation-for-real-analysis?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

For the beginner to Real analysis, I think “Introduction to Real analysis” by Bartle and Sherbert is excellent book.

Comment: Thank you! Does it have practice questions and solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I personally recommend studying analysis through '[Understanding Analysis](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=p1t1CQAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=understanding+analysis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj7trGdsNzYAhXMgLwKHZ46BYcQuwUIJzAA#v=onepage&q=understanding%20analysis&f=false)' by Stephen Abbott. I found it to be a fantastic book, with the treatment rigourous and suitable very much for beginners.

Also see this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188255/good-first-course-in-real-analysis-book-for-self-study).

Comment: Thank you! Will definitely have a look at it!